# When a spring based web application starts, it has to start with some specific URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I am starting my web application using Spring MVC.

It should **start with below URL** by default:
*http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp*

**but not with** 
*http://localhost:8080/myapp/*

Is it possible to redirect to index.jsp with using annotation (other than writing it down on web.xml as Welcomelist)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A web server does not have a current URL. You need to learn more of the basics about the web. Giving that information would amount to a tutorial, which would be too much.

Comment: I will take your word and will correct my basics. But can you please give me an idea as where should configure this to start my application with  http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp instead of  http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Comment: How do you going to `Start` web application? It will be started from URL entered by user. You can't control this moment. Possible, you would like to go to `localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp` when user types ` `localhost:8080/myapp`?

Comment: By the way, usually in Spring `.jsp` extension is not needed, because by default it is defined as suffix in `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that index.jsp is your first page, configure `web.xml` to open it first.

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

EDIT: You can define mappings in @WebConfig, and get your project started, but you will still need a web.xml welcome-file-list. See [@WebServlet annotation web.xml welcome-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507996/webservlet-annotation-web-xml-welcome-file) for some discussion.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, is it also possible to configure this using annotation.